# Problem with T distributions.

Tags: probability-distributions

In the Cambridge HL Maths Statistics & Probability section there is a chapter on t-distributions, however as per usual they do not explain where to begin with most questions.

> Assuming $T \sim t_7$ ($n=7$), solve $$P(-t < T) + P(0 < T) + P(t < T) + P(2t < T) = 1.75.$$

I began by breaking it into $$P(-t < T < 0) + 2P(0 < T <t) + 3P(t < T < 2t) + 4P(2t < T) = 1.75$$ following the areas that overlap. Now since $P(-t < T < 0) = P(0 < T <t)$, it becomes 
$$
3P(0 < T <t) + 3P(t < T < 2t) + 4P(2t < T) = 1.75 \\
3P(0 < T < 2t) + 4P(2t < T) = 1.75 \\
3P(0 < T) + P(2t < T) = 1.75
$$
and since the distribution is symmetric about 0, $P(0 < T) = 0.5$ thus
$$
P(2t < T) = 0.25
$$
giving $2t = t_7^{-1}(0.25)$ so $t = 0.359$ but in the book it is giving me a different answer. I haven't been able to find my mistake so I was hoping someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct till $P(2t<T)$. I have done some more transformations. $P(2t<T)=P(T<-2t)=0.25$. If I look at a [table](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/T-distribution-table.php) I found that $t_7^{-1}(0.25)=-t_7^{-1}(0.75)=-0.711142$.
Thus $-2t=-0.711142\Rightarrow t\approx 0.3556$

The difference is about  $0.34$ percentage points. It depends on the context if this gap makes any difference.